# how to create a cookie in nodejs socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

im trying to create a cookie while using socket.io. I am able to read cookies but cannot find any information on how to create one.

```
 socket.on('test', async function(){
    
    //  view set cookies (works!)
    console.log('cookies', socket.handshake.headers.cookie);

    // create cookie here...
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could set a cookie like you could do it in the mdn documentation with setcookies() and read it with the cookies api

Comment: i tried that apporach in the socket, but had no luck, do you have an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way as `document.cookie`, but instead of:

```js
document.cookie = ";mycookie=myval";
```

you do:

```js
socket.handshake.headers.cookie = ";mycookie=myval; expires=cookieDate; path=cookiePathOnWebsite"
```

for example:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = date.toGMTString();
socket.on('test',async function(){
  socket.handshake.headers.cookie = ";foo=bar; expires="+date+";path=/"
});
```

would set a cookie at the main page of your website, with `foo` defined as `bar`!

Comment: thank you for your comment, i tried to set a cookie using your example code, but i dont see it in : socket.handshake.headers.cookie

what am i missing here please?